In the agdrid, the date format in the date column changes on editing start. How to keep it cosistent to yyyy-mm-dd without using custom cell template?
I have date column in my react ag-grid. when I'm editing a cell in this column, I see the date format as dd-mm-yyyy. However when editing is done the format changes to yyyy-mm-dd. I want to have consistent date format throughout the grid operations. How to achieve this ?

could you provide some code to add more context

you can format the value by using the dateFormatter method
import { format } from 'date-fns';

const dateFormatter = (params) => {
  return params.value ? format(new Date(params.value), 'MM/dd/yyyy') : '';
};

....

{
  headerName: 'Date',
  field: 'date',
  editable: true,
  cellEditor: 'agTextCellEditor',
  valueFormatter: dateFormatter, 

}

